# Core Data: Fetched Results Controller causing over release/crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsentitydescription

I am using `core data`, and have a `UITableViewController` which loads the data from `core data`.  This is a `modal view` and if I load the modal view for the third time, it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create and configure a fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ride" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create the sort descriptors array
    NSSortDescriptor *sectionTitle = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateStart" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sectionTitle, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create and initialize the fetch results controller
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    // Memory management
    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sectionTitle release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;

}//end
```

The crash says that it is coming from this line:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ride" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

This is in viewDidLoad:

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) { 
        managedObjectContext = [MyAppDelegate instance].managedObjectContext; 
    }
```

Presenting the modal view:

```
History *history = [[[History alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:history] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Dismissing Modal:

```
- (void)done {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Stack Trace that gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

[image]

Now, in order to setup this view with core data, I followed the `Core Data Books` example project and my code looks almost identical.  Why would it be crashing after a few times of loading the modal view?

Comment: this code looks ok, something else is going on. if you think it has something to do with presenting the modal view multiple times check to make sure nothing is retaining the modal view when it is dismissed. Add some NSLog statements in strategic places and look at the object ID to help see what's going on.

Comment: I am just dismissing it using [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] is this a bad idea? I know apple does it differently sometimes.  There isn't anything else that I am seeing that could be causing this...but I updated my code with how I am presenting and dismissing.

Comment: can you post the crash and stack trace?

Comment: Posted the stack trace that I get on crash.

Comment: Did you enable the Zombie Objects in your Xcode Run Scheme to get more explicit information about EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Looks like someone else had this exact issue: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/74623-little-help-needed-leaks-crashes-nszombies.html

Comment: @FlorianMielke Yes, I used NSZombie and it tells me the crash is coming from the NSEntityDescription line that I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, my managedObjectContext was not being retained because I was not using self.  So, I fixed it by doing:

```
// Core Data
if (managedObjectContext == nil) { 
    self.managedObjectContext = [MyAppDelegate instance].managedObjectContext; 
}
```

Comment: I would restate your answer. Your context wasn't being retained b/c you weren't retaining it when you assigned it. By using a synthesized setter (e.g. `self.managedObjectContext = ...`) it is being retained. There are other ways you could ensure you have a valid context. You could retain it manually w/o the setter or you could refer directly to the appDelegate context w/o storing it in an iVar at all. I added this comment to (hopefully) aid in your understanding of the issue and object relationships.

Comment: I recommend you look into automatic reference counting (ARC) available in XCode 4.2. ARC let's the compiler to almost all the work wrt making sure objects are retained/released properly.

Comment: I personally don't like the idea of using ARC as I think that it leads to being a lazy programer. Not trying to say anyone else is wrong, but that is just my opinion of it.

Comment: that's fine, you're entitled to your opinion. personally, I love it. IMHO it's a perfect job for the compiler and frees us programmers to do the meat of our application rather than waste time debugging silly object allocation mistakes. I'm a strong advocate of understanding object lifecycles but am very happy spending my coding time on other things.